# HighCharts Map Drilldown - Map is rotating 180 degrees after Drillup

Tags: javascript, highcharts, categorized-highcharts-map, drilldown-highcharts-map

I am using HighCharts Map and using json data to render the USA map (I have used an SVG file and converted the SVG into json using https://highcharts.github.io/map-from-svg/ tool). I am implementing drill-down feature in the map. The drill-down works but when I click "USA" in the breadcrumb, the map rotates by 180 degrees. The expected behavior should be - The USA map should not be upside down after the drill up. I am not sure what's wrong with my code. Can anyone please provide guidance to fix the issue?

To reproduce the issue in the fiddle -

1. Click on any state in the USA map (i.e California)
2. Now click "USA" in the breadcrumbs
3. Issue - USA map is upside down now.

The complete code - https://jsfiddle.net/seaxfdrz/7/

The code snippet is -

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            drilldown,
            afterDrillUp
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Map Drilldown'
    },

    //mapView,

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        map: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#EEDD66'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: mapJason,

    drilldown: {
        activeDataLabelStyle: {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            textDecoration: 'none',
            textOutline: '1px #000000'
        },
        breadcrumbs: {
            floating: true,
            relativeTo: 'spacingBox'
        },
        drillUpButton: {
            relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
            position: {
                x: 0,
                y: 60
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a drill down from your custom SVG map, which doesn't have any projection into the TopoJSON state map, which has its built-in projection. Then, after drilling up projection is not changed and it is trying to apply projection to your custom SVG map. To resolve this problem simply change `mapView.projection.hasCoordinates` flag to `false` after drilling up.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gzqfsv63/

Comment: Ah! it does make sense. Thanks for providing the solution. Appreciate it!